# How to put different SVG into a grid with D3.js?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, grid

I have lots of svg element containing each one a line chart. I'd like to display these charts at groups of four. If I understand well from the documentation, it'd be better to use a grid for this purpose since I can select position I want (single box of the grid) for a specific graph. Is it  true, or is there another better way to do this?
NB: charts are built each one from different datasets and using d3.js and so javascript.
Thank you so much for the help.
If it's possible, I'd like you to show me a code snippet just to understand better.
Thank you again.

Comment: I forgot to say that I'd like to see the four charts in the same html page

Comment: put them in a html table or a css grid then. What exactly is your issue with doing that?

Comment: Nothing, just to know if it was a better way than using grid

Comment: Better by code quality

Comment: And how are you measuring code quality?

Comment: Well, I have been a bit inaccurate about it. It depends by multiple  factors. But for sure I meant if there was a best practice to do that, since I'm pretty a newbie in d3.js . I can't explain here in 500 characters what is code quality.

Comment: the trouble is everybody has their own idea about best practice. There's usually no single answer that everyone agrees on so those kinds of questions don't do well here. If you've some question along the lines of *I've tried this and it doesn't do what I want in this circumstance*

Comment: Ok thank you. I'll keep the advice for next questions